# Cannot read XML file using javascript other than Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following code to read an external xml file :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","myxmlfile.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

But the above code seems to work only on Firefox and not on Chrome/IE/Opera.

In Chrome I am getting an error in Console as cross domain access not allowed, but my xml file, js file and html file are all in the same folder in my local hard drive.

Any help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing your site in a server or as a local file? if your html file is local and you're opening from there, chrome won't let ajax calls fire

Comment: I am testing my site from my local hard drive. It's not only chrome, I am also unable to read the XMl file in other browsers like IE9, Opera. It works fine without any Console error in Firefox only.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably testing it locally without an http server.

Fundamentally ajax requests must be made using the same domain, if you make an ajax request to a different site it will be blocked by the browser (this is a security feature to prevent people from reading the browser's owner's data from other website). Most browsers block access to the local filesystem in the same way to protect from (for example) malicious email attachments. You'll get an error like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/your/data.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

If you are on Linux or Mac or have python installed the easiest way to start an http server is using the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in root directory of your html files, then you can view them at `http://localhost:8000/file.html` if you're on windows then you may need to configure IIS (keep in mind IIS doesn't support certain file extensions like `.json` by default so you may have to configure it).

If you still want/need to test locally without having to fiddle with an http server, then you can run Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` (either update the shortcut to the Chrome exe or run Chrome from the terminal with this switch).

Answer (score 0):

As said, you need to put your files in an http server to test correctly. You could use a local Apache instance to test it right. That way, your ajax calls won't be blocked by the browser.

Comment: So you mean all browsers except Chrome are blocking the ajax calls? I remember IE gave something that said it was unable to identify the XmlHttpRequest (Object doesn't support this method or object) when I was debugging the code. Was this the same ajax call block thing for IE? I am yet to check the error console for Opera.

Comment: If i were you, i would start by setting my server up. At least you can exclude some errors. Then, if you still have errors, we find some other solutions.