# Accessing xml file in local system

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file in my local system(not on a server). I want to access it with javascript to parse it,how can i do it? I tried giving the local file location.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","C:\Users\amit.m2\Desktop\metrics.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: @quentin I know the same question has been asked but,the answers were abstract and didn't help me solve my issue. Expecting a detailed procedure to solve this as i am new to javascript xml and ajax.

Comment: The answers on the duplicate question are not in the least bit abstract.

Comment: @quentin if u feel there are detailed answers available please do share them with me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11021628/19068

Answer (score -1):

```
  $.ajax({
          url: 'input.xml', // Name of the file in the local
          dataType: "xml", // input file type
          success: parse, // Call the parse function on success`enter code here` response
     error: 
        function(){
            alert("Unable to load or something is Wrong !!!");
         }
        });

      function parse(document){
      $(document).find("Inputdata").each(function(){
        // Business logic goes here
      });
     }
```

Comment: What is this? It looks like you've grabbed a bunch of code that works for you without trying to understand why the OPs code isn't working for them (so it might fix the problem by eliminating an error, or it might not because the problem could be unrelated to the code (e.g. same origin policy) (in this case, it won't)). Either way, it completely lacks any explanation and reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.